# How to create a lettered list using docx?

Tags: python, python-2.x, nested-lists, python-docx

I use python for teaching some of my science courses, where I use it to generate unique assignments and tests for students. I've run into an issue that I can't sort out on my own.

I'm trying to make a series of nested lists. For example, I would like to have a numbered question, and then sub parts to the question underneath. For example:

1. Use the Henderson-Hasselbalch equation to determine pH of the following solutions:
     A. 250 mM Ammonium Chloride
     B. 100 mM Acetic Acid

I've used style "List Number" to create the numbered list, but I can't figure out how to create a custom list that starts with the letters.

Here is what I've got so far:

```
import sys
import os

if os.uname()[1] == 'iMac':
    sys.path.append("/Users/mgreene3/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages")
else:
    sys.path.append("/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python")

import numpy as np
import math
import random
import textwrap

from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt, Inches
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE
from docx.text.tabstops import TabStop as ts
from docx.text.parfmt import ParagraphFormat

assignment = Document()
ordered = "a"


style = assignment.styles["Normal"]
font = style.font
font.name = "Calibri"
font.size = Pt(12)
style.paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(0)

LetteredList = style.paragraph_format._NumberingStyle(ordered)

sub_style = assignment.styles["ListBullet"]
sub_font = sub_style.font
sub_font.name = "Calibri"
###sub_style.paragraph_format.style("List")
sub_font.size = Pt(12)
sub_style.paragraph_format.left_indent = Inches(1)
sub_style.paragraph_format.space_before = Pt(0)
sub_style.paragraph_format.space_after = Pt(40)

doc_heading = assignment.add_paragraph("Name:_______________________")
doc_heading.add_run("\t" * 4)
doc_heading.add_run(" " * 12)
doc_heading.add_run("BIOL444: Biochemistry\t\t\t\t\t\t   ")
doc_heading.add_run("\n")
doc_heading.add_run("Take Home 1, v.")
doc_heading.add_run((str(1).zfill(2)))
doc_heading.add_run("\n" * 2)
doc_heading.add_run("Instructions: Complete test (")
show_work = doc_heading.add_run("show work")
show_work.bold = True
show_work.underline = True
show_work
doc_heading.add_run("), submit ")
hard_copy = doc_heading.add_run("hard copy")
hard_copy.bold = True
hard_copy.underline = True
hard_copy
doc_heading.add_run(" by ")
doc_heading.add_run("11:59 pm, Friday, February 10").bold =True
doc_heading.add_run(". Late submissions will ")
doc_heading.add_run("NOT").bold=True
doc_heading.add_run(" be accepted.")


question1 = assignment.add_paragraph("Using the data for K", style = "List Number")
question1.add_run("a").font.subscript = True
question1.add_run(" and pK")
question1.add_run("a").font.subscript = True
question1.add_run(" of the following compounds, calculate the concentrations (M) of all ionic species as well as the pH of the following aqueous solutions: ")
question1.add_run("\n")

question1a = assignment.add_paragraph("100 mM Acetic acid", style = sub_style)
question1b = assignment.add_paragraph("250 mM NaOH", style = sub_style)


assignment.save("TestDocx.docx")
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: I'll post what I have so far. The second list, the lettered list, I want to classify under the "sub_style" I have created.

Comment: Why does it need to be `.docx`?

Comment: I will always recommend LaTeX for document formatting.  If you are comfortable using python, there are some good libraries to generate LaTeX documents.

Comment: It doesn't have to be docx, that's just what I've familiar with. I'm happy to try and use another library. I'm unfamiliar with LaTex; is this easter to use?

Comment: @Matt no it's not

Comment: [rst](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html) in combination with a templating engine (Jinja?) might be a lot more versatile and easy

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it's probably more trouble than it's worth. Creating numbered lists, especially nested numbered lists in Word is a complex operation, possibly for legacy reasons (we're on version 14 or something of Word). Partly because of this complexity, API support for this doesn't yet exist in `python-docx`.

If you really wanted to do it, it would entail manipulating numbering definitions that exist in another package part from the document part (I believe it's numbering.xml). This would be using low-level lxml calls.

For myself, I'd be strongly inclined to use RestructuredText for a job like this, rendering to PDF, perhaps using Sphinx. As a side-effect, you could easily get HTML version as well for posting assignments on the web. However, I'm too far away from your actual requirements to say that would really suit; you'll have to check it out and see for yourself :)